# Rails minitest assert_equal assert_match regexp question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

I need to assert if a returned string contains one or another substring.

I'm writing it like this:

```
if mail.subject.include?('Pragmatic Store Order Confirmation')
      assert_equal 'Pragmatic Store Order Confirmation', mail.subject
    else
      assert_equal 'There was an error with your payment', mail.subject
    end
```

However I would like to know how to write it as one line with assert_equal or assert_match
I tried

```
assert_match( /(Pragmatic Store Order Confirmation) (There was an error with your payment)/, mail.subject )
```

But i just cant figure out how it or regexp works. Hope I've made myself clear.
Thanks!

Comment: `include` is not checking a string for a regex match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the basic idea, but the regex is wrong.

```
/(Pragmatic Store Order Confirmation) (There was an error with your payment)/
```

That will match "Pragmatic Store Order Confirmation There was an error with your payment" and capture "Pragmatic Store Order Confirmation" and "There was an error with your payment".

If you want to match something *or* something else, use a `|`.

```
/(Pragmatic Store Order Confirmation|There was an error with your payment)/
```

[Try it](https://regex101.com/r/EsKxee/1)

---

However, an exact match is better done with [`assert_include`](https://test-unit.github.io/test-unit/en/Test/Unit/Assertions.html#assert_include-instance_method).

```
subjects = [
  'Pragmatic Store Order Confirmation',
  'There was an error with your payment'
]
assert_include subjects, mail.subject
```

That is equivalent to `subjects.include?(mail.subject)`.

---

Finally, one should question why the test does not know which subject line the mail will have. It should depend on why the mail was generated. Your test should be something like...

```
if payment_error
  assert_equal 'There was an error with your payment', mail.subject
else
  assert_equal 'Pragmatic Store Order Confirmation', mail.subject
end
```